# A query with 3 tables in django

Tags: sql, django

I have 3 classes like this:

```
class Person (models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Device (models.Model)
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Uses (models.Model)
   ....
 person_name =  models.ForeignKey(Person)
 person_device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
```

My question is: How can I make a query to get the devices used by the person "name"? Which needs to pass through the uses class.

Comment: Could you provide the name of the foreign keys used in the class Uses? Such as `device=models.ForeignKey(Device)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life will be easier if you use ManyToManyField, i.e. add this field to the Person model:

```
devices = models.ManyToManyField('Device', through='Uses')
```

Then, to get the list, you just need to get the devices attribute of the model object:

```
Person.objects.get(name="TheNameYouWant").devices
```

If you do not want to modify the model, the list of devices used by a person could be retrieved as below:

```
Device.objects.filter(uses__person_name__name="TheNameYouWant")
```

If Django say cannot resolve keyword "uses" into filed, please change to "uses_set". I can't remember which one is which.

Comment: @user2137817, which method did you use?

Comment: last one : Device.objects.filter(uses__person_name__name="TheNameYouWant")

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that what you have written is the only thing in your classes, i.e. that is your entire `models.py` file.

So, now you wish to know how you can link these tables together. The answer is simple, all you have to do is use one of the many relationship files that django provides in order to create a relationship between tables.

Now the relationship can be different, heck *how* the relationship works between the two tables may also be of importance. Django makes all of this possible, and take a look at the the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). First one needs to establish the kind of relationship, so say a `Person` can have many `Devices`. So, this is how your new `Person` class would look like:

```
class Person (models.Model)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And this is how your `Device` class would look like:

```
class Device (models.Model)
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   user = model.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Note that you do not change the `Person` class, this is how a `Many-To-One` relationship works in django. You can have a look at how this all works in the documentation link I provided above.

Now as for querying, you can simply do this:

```
Device.objects.filter(user__name='<name_you_want>')
```

Comment: Thank you for the infos :) I know how to make a query between 2 tables but the problem is between 3 tables and the 3 one contain all the foreign keys

Comment: @user2137817: Same principle. So something like `Devices.objects.filter(user__devices__uses__main_use='reading news')`, here `main_user` is a made up property inside one of your models.

Comment: i got the cannot resolve keyboard 'user' into field or user is a model

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make a query to get the devices used by the person "name"?

```
devices = Uses.objects.filter(person_name__name='name').values_list('person_device')
```